# How to clean my repository in Tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have an Assembla repository and I use Tortoise SVN.

The files and versions are a mess so I wanted to go back to an older version. I used the option "Checkout SVN" to get that version in my computer.

Now I want to transfer everything I have on my computer to the repository (and the delete the stuff that is there).

I could erase everything in the repository but I don't want to lose the info, the versions, etc.

I tried doing Commit but the option to transfer the files that you didn't modify isn't there.

Comment: @Michael-O: This question is on-topic here. Tortoise SVN is a commonly used programmer's tool, and questions about its operation are acceptable here. (And the question would be off-topic for SuperUsers; please be familiar with the guidelines for both the site you're trying to migrate from and the site you're suggesting they ask instead.)

Comment: I don't think this question is clear. When you say an "older version", do you mean a previous revision of the repository that is not the head? What changes are you trying to preserve? Changes you have made locally or changes others have made and committed? Could you be more specific about what "a mess" is? Conflicts? Just changes you want to undo?

Comment: Basically I want to go back to a previous revision. I can do it on my computer (Checkout on another folder), but cannot do it in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a fresh copy of the repository at the **head** revision.

In Windows Explorer,

Right Click the top of your repository --> TortoiseSVN --> Show Log

Find the revision you want to go back to, and right click. Choose "Revert to this revision". (**Do not** confuse this with "Revert changes from this revision".) Confirm that you really want to do this.

This will revert all those changes **in your local copy**. To get your repository back to that revision, just commit these local changes. (And document clearly in your commit message that you reverted back to a particular revision.)

I think that's probably the easiest way to do it. You can't expunge the bad revisions from SVN's record, to my knowledge, and there isn't a whole lot of benefit in doing so unless you have sensitive information that accidentally got added.

Comment: Thanks. I did checkout in another folder and deleted everything. Then I copied all those files to that folder and used Commit. Thanks!